# How can I use mmCIF format instead PDB in BioJava?

Tags: java, protein-database, biojava

I have a small problem...

I know that for download a PDB structure using BioJava I should use

```
Structure s = StructureIO.getStructure("code");
```

What I should do to use mmCIF file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the latest BioJava, the default is already to use mmcif. You can configure this in the AtomCache class (and set a custom cache in StructureIO)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try